# sorting a dictionary and printing key value pairs

Tags: dictionary, sorting, printing

trying to sort a dictionary for a high score list and then print the key/value pairs sorted

this is what i have , it only prints the value.

I have a horrible feeling that the sorted list I am making only contains the values not the keys and that's why I can't do it. Advice please

scores = {
"Bob":21,
"Ed":23,
"Tony":45,
"Mary":66}

sorted_scores = sorted(scores.values(),reverse =True)

print('The First 3 Highscores are:')
for x in sorted_scores[:3]:
print(x)

Tried a whole bunch of variations, non of them working. looking for a way for the sorted list to sort by the values but include both the key and value for printing.

Comment: Use `.items()` instead of `.values()` to get the (key, value) pairs instead of just the values.

Comment: that sorts on the key. not the value. tried it.  i did find a work around making a new key and having the name and score in a tuple like 1 : (24,"Bob") but i dont like it much.

Comment: Function `sorted` can take a `key` function as an extra argument to tell it how to sort. See my answer. Also I strongly suggest you read [Sorting HOW-TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sortinghowto) from the python documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.items()` instead of `.values` if you want (key, value) pairs instead of just values.

```py
from operator import itemgetter

scores = { "Bob":21, "Ed":23, "Tony":45, "Mary":116}

sorted_scores = sorted(scores.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

print('The First 3 Highscores are:')
for name,score in sorted_scores[:3]:
    print(f'{name:10s}{score:3d}')

# Mary      116
# Tony       45
# Ed         23
```

Alternatively, if the dictionary is large but you're only interested in a small number of highscores, then you can use `heapq.nlargest`:

```py
from heapq import nlargest
from operator import itemgetter

scores = { "Bob":21, "Ed":23, "Tony":45, "Mary":116}
highscores = nlargest(3, scores.items(), key=itemgetter(1))

print('The First 3 Highscores are:')
for name,score in highscores:
    print(f'{name:10s}{score:3d}')

# Mary      116
# Tony       45
# Ed         23
```